# Is there any way to give numbering to all the co-ordinates of the line chart in FUSION CHARTS FREE

Tags: graph, fusioncharts

I created a fusion line chart using the following:

```
  var chart = new FusionCharts("Charts/FCF_MSLine.swf", "chart_id", "600", "500");
  chart.setDataXML(XmlData);
  chart.render("divDisplay");
```

I am getting a line chart which is having many co-ordinates but the co=ordinate points are not named. 
**

> The co-ordinate point values must
>   appear for the co-ordinate point in
>   the line garph. Is there any way to
>   achieve this.

** 
PLz help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try once using `showValues='1'` in `<graph>`  or in `<dataset>` if you wish to show all the values of the anchors (co-ordinate points) of each line.

If you already have `showValues='0'` in `<graph>` or in `<dataset>` please set to 1.

Hope this helps.

Additionally, please provide here the XML which you use for debugging the issue.

Please try the XML shown below:

```
<graph showValues='0'  caption='February Peak Load vs. Today' xAxisName='Hour Ending' yAxisName='Load (MW)' >
    <categories>
      <category name='1' />
      <category name='2' />
      <category name='3' />
      <category name='4' />
      <category name='5' />
      <category name='6' />

   </categories>
   <dataset seriesname='Current Day 2/3/05' color='0099FF' showValues='1' >
      <set value='1188' />
      <set value='1189' />
      <set value='1177' />
      <set value='1175' />
      <set value='1210' />
      <set value='1280' />

   </dataset>
   <dataset seriesname='February Peak Load' color='FF8000'  alpha='80' showAnchors='0'>
      <set value='1550' />
      <set value='1550' />
      <set value='1550' />
      <set value='1550' />
      <set value='1550' />
      <set value='1550' />

   </dataset>
</graph>
```

Comment: Hi I tried showValues='1'. But still its not showing the co-ordinate values for the coordinate points. Is there any woraround for to achieve this.

Comment: Please provide here the XML which you are using

Comment: It is also important to check if you have showValues in both `<graph>` and `<dataset>`. In case you have `showValues='1'` in `<graph>` please set `showValues='1'` in `<dataset>`. Make sure of the spelling. It ends with `s'.

Comment: It worked!! THANK YOU SOOOOOOO MUCH FOR SUCH A SPEEDY HELP. Hatts Off. :) :).   The co-ordinate values are appearing. ONE MORE SMALL HELP.  MY LINE GRAPH IS HAVING MANY CURVES, SO SOME OF THE CO-ORDINATES VALUES WHICH ARE APPEARING FOR THE CORRESPONDIN POINTS ARE OVER WRITTEN BY THE LINE CONNECTING THE POINTS. IS THERE ANY WAY TO DISPLAY THE COORDINATE VALUES SUCH THAT THE LINES DOES NOT INTERSECT THE VALUES DISPLAYED.

Comment: Or the workaround would be to make the coordinate values in BOLD font and at the same draw the line in light color.  IS THERE ANY WAY TO MAKE THE COORDINATE VALUES BOLD.

Comment: As of now you can not selectively hide values in FusionCharts FREE. This is possible using FusionCharts v3 (http://www.fusioncharts.com). Again, using FusionCharts v3 you can rotate values, set font to bold or put background color and border color etc. on the value.